# Is $K_n$ compact in $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider $X=l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ the space 
of all bounded sequence of real numbers endowed with the sup norm. 
I would like to know two thinks about this  Banach space:

1. Are  the sets $K_n=[-n,n]^{\mathbb{N}}$  compacts?
2. Has the  sets $K_n=[-n,n]^{\mathbb{N}}$ non empty interior?

Note: I'd like to know this thinks to overlap some technical
issues in a problem that I'm working.

Comment: What is the open ball of radius 1 centered at 0 in your space?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  I see, this $K_n$ are at last closed?

Comment: What do you see?

Comment: I see that $K_n$ are not compact because it contains a non compact set...

Comment: Well, that is not true: the interval $[0,1]$ is compact and yet it contains the non-compact set $(0,1)$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $K_{n}$ is the closed ball centered at 0 and with radius $n$ in your space. So it has a non-empty interior. It is not compact: the sequences $s_{n}$ such that $s_{n}(m) = \delta_{n,m}$ are a sequence in your space that has no convergent subsequence, because $\lVert s_{n}-s_{m} \rVert = 1$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you tell me If this $K_n $ are closed?

Comment: They are closed, because a closed ball is closed.